# Price low and High search

Tags: mysql, perl, search, range

I'm using the code snipet below to search price ranges. If I search 1-600 dollars as low-high, results include prices like 22,500. The column is varchar. Thanks

```
if (($price_low) && ($price_high)){
$statement .= " OR item_price BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
push(@binds,$price_low,$price_high);
}
elsif (($price_low) && ($price_high eq "")){
$statement .= " OR item_price > ? ";
push(@binds,$price_low);
}
elsif (($price_high) && ($price_low eq "")){
$statement .= " OR item_price BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
push(@binds,1,$price_high);
}
else {  }
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq(SELECT * FROM ads WHERE $statement )) or  die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->execute(@binds);
```

Comment: If in your database the price is representing dollars, why use varchar rather than a numerical datatype?

Comment: So values in the `item_price` column in the database are numbers which have been formatted as strings, including comma separators? That type of formatting would usually be performed at output time rather than before storing in the DB.

Comment: Can you really use `BETWEEN` and `>` for a varchar column without explicitly casting the data as a number?

Comment: You also have a little logic error. What happens if either `$price_low` or `$price_high` are zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

> *The column is varchar.*

That, and your formatting within the column, is the problem here.  For the row you mention, you are essentially doing this:

```
> SELECT '22,500' BETWEEN 1 AND 600;
```

MySQL will forcibly convert the *string* `'22,500'` to a numeric value, chopping off everything after (and including) the first comma.  So, an `item_price` of `'22,500'` becomes 22, which of course is BETWEEN 1 AND 600.  (What happens if you SHOW WARNINGS after you execute your statement?  I think you'll see a warning about incorrect DOUBLE truncation...)

Convert your column to a bona fide numeric type, and try your query again.  (Fixing the issue @CanSpice pointed out...)

Comment: umm..i've tried TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT, INT and DECIMAL from numeric choices and none will work. Can someone recommend the correct choice?

Comment: @ta: Show us exactly what doesn't work, and exactly how to reproduce the failure.

Comment: After changing the column to INT in mysql admin then changing the price to 22,500 in mysql admin I get this error: 0 rows affected.
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'item_price' at row 1

Comment: Ok. I've got INT working. Apparently you have to remove the commas first. Thanks